# Search as-you-type from UISearchBar in a UITableView with multiple sections?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, uisearchbar

So I'm currently listening to a text change from the searchBar:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)searchText
{    
      [self filterContentForSearchText:searchText]; 
}
```

I want to design a method `filterContentForsearchText` such that it automatically filters through my UITableView as I type.

The problem I'm having is that my UITableView is complicated. It has multiple sections with multiple fields. It's basically an contact/address book that is an array of arrays that holds contact objects.

`CustomContact *con = [contacts[section_of_contact] allValues][0][x]` where x is a specific row in that section returns a CustomContact "con" that has properties like `con.fullName`.

The UITableView currently displays fullNames of contacts in separate sections. How can I filter through this structure of an array/UITableView as I type using my `UISearchBar`?

Here's how the table is filled:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    BrowseContactCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BROWSECELL"];

    CustomContact *thisContact = [self.contacts[indexPath.section] allValues][0][indexPath.row];

        cell.labelName.text = thisContact.fullName;

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also created an address-book with sections (an array of arrays), so I'll just post my solution, which is  however not my own solution (I somewhere found it here on stackoverflow some time ago):

In your `UITableViewController` subclass just add the following two `UISearchDisplayDelegate` methods ([link to the api reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchDisplayDelegate)) and the "custom" method `filterContentForSearchText` to filter through your array. For better understanding, please read my comments in the code blocks. Further questions or ideas for improvement are always welcome.

```
#pragma mark - search Display Controller Delegate

- (BOOL) searchDisplayController : (UISearchDisplayController *) controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString : (NSString *) searchString {

    [self filterContentForSearchText : searchString
                               scope : [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                       objectAtIndex : [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Search Filter

- (void) filterContentForSearchText : (NSString*) searchText
                              scope : (NSString*) scope {
    // Here, instead of "lastName" or "firstName" just type your "fullName" a.s.o.
    // I have also a custom NSObject subclass like your CustomContact that holds 
    //these strings like con.firstName or con.lastName
    NSPredicate* resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat : @" (lastName beginswith %@) OR (firstName beginsWith %@)", searchText, searchText];

    // For this method, you just don't need to take your partitioned and 
    // somehow complicated contacts array (the array of arrays). 
    // Instead, just take an array that holds all your CustomContacts (unsorted):
    NSArray* contactsArray = // here, get your unsorted contacts array from your data base or somewhere else you have stored your contacts;

    // _searchResults is a private NSArray property, declared in this .m-file 
    // you will need this later (see below) in two of your UITableViewDataSource-methods:
    _searchResults = [contactsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate : resultPredicate];

    // this is just for testing, if your search-Filter is working properly.
    // Just remove it if you don't need it anymore
    if (_searchResults.count == 0) {
        NSLog(@" -> No Results (If that is wrong: try using simulator keyboard for testing!)");
    } else {
        NSLog(@" -> Number of search Results: %d", searchResults.count);
    }
}
```

Now, you need to do some changes to your following three `UITableViewDataSource`-methods:

**Note**: the searchResultsTableView is also loaded with the normal common data source 
methods that are usually called to fill your (sectioned address-book-)tableView:

**1.**

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView : (UITableView *) tableView
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
         // in our searchTableView we don't need to show the sections with headers
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return [[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles] count];
    }
}
```

**2.**

```
- (NSInteger) tableView : (UITableView *) tableView
  numberOfRowsInSection : (NSInteger) section {

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        // return number of search results
        return [_searchResults count];
    } else {
        // return count of the array that belongs to that section
        // here, put (or just let it there like before) your 
        // [contacts[section] allValues][count]
       return [[currentMNFaces objectAtIndex : section] count];
    }    
}
```

**3.**

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView : (UITableView *) tableView
          cellForRowAtIndexPath : (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

    BrowseContactCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BROWSECELL"];
CustomContact *thisContact = nil;

    // after loading your (custom) UITableViewCell
    // you probably might load your object that will be put into the 
    // labels of that tableCell.
    // This is the point, where you need to take care if this is your
    // address-book tableView that is loaded, or your searchTable:

    // load object...    
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        // from search list
        faceAtIndex = [self->searchResults objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    } else {
        // from your contacts list
        contactAtIndex = [self.contacts[indexPath.section] allValues][0][indexPath.row];
    }

    }
```

Hope that works for you.

Comment: Awesome! I'll take a look through your code and see if it works out for me (and what modifications I make if any).

Comment: @Rohan you're welcome. Would be so happy if you marked my (first) answer as a correct answer in case it worked for you :-)

Comment: will do, still messing around with it -- will be sure to give you credit when I'm done

Comment: I'm really close -- getting a tiny error in how the predicate was formed: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string (lhs = (
    "Anna Pediatrician"
) rhs = p)'   ---- I typed in "p" and it returned this exception. Why doesn't it recognize my fullName attribute (Anna Pediatrician) as a string?

Comment: Thanks for voting up my answer. Since you marked it as correct, did you fix your error with that string problem?

Comment: it says "No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'searchDisplayController:willShowSearchResultsTableView:' inside the - (void) searchDisplayController : (UISearchDisplayController*) controller willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView method

Comment: I think this might be a new question? Did you add a `Search Bar and Search Display Controller` with IB (Interface Builder)? If you are not using IB add `<UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>`in the header file of your TableViewController

Comment: ...and don't forget to follow the instructions at [UISearchDisplayController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISearchDisplayController)